# jQuery re-order elements by tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am currently trying to re-order an unordered list of elements by their `rel="1234"` tag associated with each using jQuery.

However, my current code is causing the output not to appear and I cannot work out why. Can anyone help?

My jQuery code is:

```
$(function(){
    var elems = $('#test').children('li').remove();
    elems.sort(function(a,b){
        return parseInt(a.attr('rel')) > parseInt(b.attr('rel'));
    });
    $('#test').append(elems);
});
```

With basic mark-up like this:

```
<ul id="test">
    <li rel="4112">blub</li>
    <li rel="1422">blaaah</li>
    <li rel="6640">hmmmm</li>
    <li rel="2221">one more</li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BQZHC/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:-

```
$(function(){
    var elems = $('#test').children('li'); // You dont need to remove the elements
    elems.sort(function(a,b){
         return +$(a).attr('rel') > +$(b).attr('rel'); // use attr on jquery object i.e $(a), $(b)
    });
    $('#test').append(elems); // This will take care of repositioning the elements.
});
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5LPAM/)

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want

JS:

```
var elems = $('#test').children('li').remove();
elems.sort(function(a,b){
    return parseInt($(a).attr('rel'), 10) > parseInt($(b).attr('rel'), 10);
});
$('#test').html(elems);
```

Note that the "a" and "b" elements of your sort function shoud be treated as jQuery objects. Also you should specify the radix of the `parseInt()`

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/BQZHC/10/

Answer (score 0):

`a` and `b` are DOM elements, not jQuery objects.

Either wrap them with `$()` to make jQuery objects, or use `getAttribute("rel")` instead of `.attr("rel")`. It'ss a little longer, but requires less overhead.

---

Additionally, assuming you wanted a numeric ordering, I would use subtraction.

```
return a.getAttribute("rel") - b.getAttribute("rel");
```

There have been browsers in the past that have had issues with returning a boolean value.